# Docker for Microservice app

Tags: playframework, docker

I'm working on a new microservice based server.
For the purpose of simplifying our daily work, I though of using multiple docker containers that each one runs a different micro service.
We're developing on Windows but the code will eventually run on Linux.

What would be the best approach?
(1) Each build, copy the target files to the relevant container?
(2) Share my source code with the containers and build/run in each container?
(3) Share my target files with each container?
(4) Other?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your development environment you could volume mount the binaries directory of your IDE. This would decrease the feedback loop for your local development environment. You would not have to rebuild the image each time, just restarting the container. This even works out for Windows under boot2docker.
- After commiting your code to the source control system you should apply a release pipeline/stream/train for building the related docker image put a build number on it. Tag and release it into your private docker registry.
- Skript all environments to safely switch to the latest docker image. Test the setup and when errors occurs then revert to former docker container. If its safe then roll it out on the next stage.
- Roll out database changes by utility containers that run database clients.